# C++ delete[] calls destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, operator-keyword

**EDITED : added constructor and destructor.**

EDIT : this is the leak :

```
c:\users\sijaan\desktop\1\starray.cpp(61) : {148} normal block at 0x007C0910, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <        h |     > C8 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 68 09 7C 00 CD CD CD CD 
c:\users\sijaan\desktop\1\starray.cpp(43) : {145} normal block at 0x007C04B0, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <d         {     > 64 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 A8 E2 7B 00 CD CD CD CD 
c:\users\sijaan\desktop\1\starray.cpp(24) : {143} normal block at 0x007C0150, 816 bytes long.
 Data: <    X {         > 80 00 00 00 58 E1 7B 00 CE CD CD CD CE CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

I'm trying to create a new object after every call for this function :

```
    bool StArray::addCS_Course(int StudentID, int CourseID, char * CourseName, int HwNum, double HwWeigh, int Flag, char * BookName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENT_NUM; i++) {
        if (StArray_[i] == NULL) continue;
        if (StArray_[i]->getID() == StudentID) {

            CS_Course* New_CS = new CS_Course(CourseID, CourseName, HwNum, HwWeigh, Flag, BookName);

            StArray_[i]->addCS_Course(New_CS);
            return true;
        }

    }
        return false;
}
```

should I use new to do this? or the constructor itself makes an  object to be used outside this function?

Here's the class declaration :

```
class CS_Course : public Course {

public:
    /*Interface functions*/
    /* *****************************************************
    Function: CS_Course
    Abstract: constructor
    Parameters: 
        Course_Id : course number
        Course_Name : course name
        Hw_Num : homeworks number
        Hw_Weigh : the weigh of the homeworks
    Return Value: 
    ***************************************************** */
    CS_Course(int Course_ID, char* Course_Name, int Hw_Num, double Hw_Weigh, int flag, char* BookName); // constructor
    ~CS_Course();

private:
    int flag_;
char* BookName_;
```

I'm asking this because of that when I'm deleting the CourseName string and the BookName, I'' still have a new allocated object which has nothing.
Then Im doing this : `delete[] pCSC[j];` pCSC has pointers to the CS_Course.
But I get an error because this delete calls the CS_Course destructor  which trys to destroy the CourseName which I already destroyed.

This is the constructor :

```
CS_Course::CS_Course(int Course_ID, char * Course_Name, int Hw_Num, double Hw_Weigh, int flag, char * BookName)
    :Course(Course_ID, Course_Name, Hw_Num, Hw_Weigh), flag_(flag)
{
    BookName_ = new char[strlen(BookName) + 1];
    strcpy(BookName_, BookName);
}
```

and this is the destructor :

```
CS_Course::~CS_Course() 
{
    delete[] BookName_;
}
```

Comment: You almost never should use `new`/`new[]` or `delete`/`delete[]` in your code. Do you have a really good reason?

Comment: Side note: You do (in most cases) something wrong when you place allocated memory into a container (if you need polymorphism you should use a std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr)

Comment: The fact that you are neither using standard types (like `std::vector` or `std::string`) suggests that you should read a good tutorial. Anyhow, in general, avoid use of `new` and `delete` if possible. If you do, use smart pointers, not raw pointers. However, I wonder what the relation to you subject "delete[] calls destructor" is. If you can, please also extract a minimal example, see the posting guidelines for further info.

Comment: How do I create a new object without the new operator? and how I pass its address as an argument to another function?

Comment: @SijaanHallak _"How do I create a new object?"_ You just create one using it's constructor on the stack. _"and how I pass its address "_ You just pass a reference, that's sufficient.

Comment: @SijaanHallak "How do I create a new object without the new operator?" That's C++ basics right there. When you initialize an object with the new keyword it adds it to the Heap(your RAM). Meanwhile, doing so through just the constructor it is initialized on the stack.

Comment: @Krythic I'm doing it right then.
I still cant delete this new allocated object. I'm deleting it's new allocated fields first. But when I try to delete the object as a whole (the Class itself) the delete calls its destructor, which I dont want, because the destructor tries again to delete the fields.
I need to delete the Object itslef! How to do so?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not allowed to use neither vector nor string

Comment: @SijaanHallak You <Trademark>shouldn't</Trademark> need to release memory if you initialize it on the stack, this is due the fact that those objects are deleted when the stack unwinds(at the end the final function bracket). The only time you <Trademark>should</Trademark> need to worry about deleting anything is when you initialize a class with "new".

Comment: @Krythic Look at the function. I;m initializing it on the Heap.
new is necessary here

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Add your code where you actual delete the objects, remove the code, which has nothing to do with your problem, state exactly what you want, and exactly whats the problem. I.e. read the guideline of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

The `new` here is necessary, since you are passing a pointer to the newly created object. If you were creating a local variable and passing it, it wont be available outside this function.

Also, make sure to `delete` the objects when you no longer needed (i.e. if you remove it from the array). otherwise it will cause a memory leak.

Comment: Well, this is what I'm trying to do when I no longer need it. But it gives me an error that I'm deleting a nullptr.

Comment: Added definitions of the const and destr.

Answer (score 0):

You're used to C and switch to C++ now, aren't you?

**EDIT:**

You often, you don't have to allocate something at all:

```
class CS_Course : public Course {
public:
    CS_Course(int Course_ID, char* Course_Name, int Hw_Num, double Hw_Weigh, int flag,char* BookName) 
    :Course(Course_ID, Course_Name, Hw_Num, Hw_Weigh), flag_(flag), BookName(BooName)
    {
    }
private:
    int flag_;
    std::string BookName_;
};
```

Allocating data structures in functions is something you can't avoid in C, but in C++! Never use raw `new`s in modern C++ code!

Use the new smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

They allow you to do exactly what you wan't without any problems about double deleting.

Also try to not use the built in C data types. Use `std::string` instead of `char*`, i.e. `const std::string &` instead of `const char*` and `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of built in arrays!

Comment: I just switched to C++ (2 weeks ago).
I'm not allowed to use smart pointers

Comment: But you're allowed to use `std::string` aren't you?

Comment: I'm sorry but not be allowed to use `std::string` is just senseless and stupid. You're basically still writing C. Aren't you allowed to at least write your own string class?

Comment: I just have a leak problem which I need to be fixed. that's all!
do you have any suggesting on how to delete the new CS_Course ?

Comment: @SijaanHallak If you're _not allowed_ to use basic c++ features, what's the reason to stick with that non c++ teaching course now? Just blame the teacher, or leave that course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just need an answer of how to free the new allocated object.

Comment: @SijaanHallak You just need to provide a [MCVE] in your question (especially where `new` allocated values will be stored at), to get concise answers. Voted your question as off-topic now.

Comment: @SijaanHallak No you're asking a XY-question ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 ) , to delete something you allocated with `new` use `delete` i.e. `new[]` and `delete[]`. Otherwise your problem relies on your structure of your code. And since you don't give enough information about your code nor as we can change it, nor what you want, as I said in the comments of your question, we can't give you further answers, yet

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I managed to solve it! I was calling twice for the destructor.